# Turning a decimal back into it's Reciprocal?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So when you have a number:
5, the reciprocal would be 1/5 and in decimals 0.2

To go from decimal back to the original number i can just go:
0.2 x 5^2 
= 5

But what happens when i don't know the starting number (x) but just the decimal? 
x = 0.2x^2
:. x/x^2 = 0.2
:. x/x = sqrt(0.2)

Where do i go from here (x/x)? Or did i get this wrong from the start of it? Also if there is any already completed methods of finding the number of a reciprocal in decimal form that would be great.

Comment: Hint: The reciprocal of the reciprocal of a number is the original number.  For instance the reciprocal of $5$ is $\frac{1}{5}$ and the reciprocal of $\frac{1}{5}$ is back to $5$.

Comment: You were correct in saying that $x=0.2 x^2$ but you manipulated it incorrectly: $x=0.2x^2 \Rightarrow x/x^2=0.2 \Rightarrow 1/x = 0.2 \Rightarrow x = 1/0.2$ which is what others wrote in their answers.

Answer (score 1):

To find the reciprocal of a number, you divide it into $1$.  For instance, the reciprocal of $0.2$ is

$$1 \div 0.2 = 5$$

while the reciprocal of $0.375$ is

$$\frac{1}{0.375} = \frac{1 \cdot 1000}{0.375 \cdot 1000} = \frac{1000}{375} = \frac{8 \cdot 125}{3 \cdot 125} = \frac{8}{3}$$

which is the reciprocal of

$$\frac{3}{8} = \frac{3 \cdot 125}{8 \cdot 125} = \frac{375}{1000} = 0.375$$

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to use the fact that $1/(1/x)=x$ so taking the reciprocal twice leads to the original number. Therefore the reciprocal of the reciprocal of a number is the number.